# How to search from list by ElementName If my List is Stored with a Name in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here is the Structure of my `MongoDB` `Document`

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("56daf32732e68d206fac1841"),
        "users" : [
                {
                        "Id" : 1,
                        "FirstName" : "noname",
                        "email" : "NoName625@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                        "Id" : 2,
                        "FirstName" : "abc",
                        "email" : "abc@abc.com"
                },
                {
                        "Id" : 3,
                        "FirstName" : "Krishna",
                        "email" : "Krishna85@gmail.com"
                }
        ]  }
```

And I want to perform search using `FirstName` as Parameters. Is it possible to get Result like this

```
 {
   "Id" : 3,
   "FirstName" : "Krishna",
   "email" : "Krishna85@gmail.com"
 }
```

If I want to search using the parameters `FirstName` to Get Result.

> **Question** :Write a `Query` for this.

Comment: You can use the Aggregation's "unwind" operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the *$* projection operator
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

```
db.Collection.find({ "users.FirstName": 'Krishna'} , { "users.$.FirstName" : 1 })
```

Result will be:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56daf32732e68d206fac1841"),
  "users": [{
      "Id": 3,
      "FirstName": "Krishna",
      "email": "Krishna85@gmail.com"
  }]
}
```

To format result as you want it to be (if you still wants to do so), you will have to use the aggregation framework and format the result using *$project*
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/